# C# UWP Assigned Access Dispatch from Thread to UI Thread

Tags: c#, events, win-universal-app, ui-thread, kiosk-mode

when I call this in a async task in my app **in assigned access**

```
await CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () => OnFaceDetected(false));
```

I'm became this error :

System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

but when I run the app **wihtout the assigned access all works fine**

Comment: This has nothing to do with threads. You tried to acces an empty variable. Debug your code and check which of the objects is null

Comment: The code works as a normal app, but when I start the app in the assigned access there is the error